# Serial-sided polygons with given angle condition

Tags: probability, polygons

> A serial-sided polygon is a polygon with side-lengths equal to $1,2,\dotsb,n$ in a random order. For a given positive integer $n$, what is the probability that a serial-suded polygon has an angle between $30^°$,$60^°$?

I've only been able to try the complex-plane representation of polygons that has lead to absolutely nothing. The only fact I have is the trivial statement that any of the polygons that don't satisfy the condition shall have numerous angles more that 60 since they can't have all of their angles less then 30. (As said, trivial)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do the side lengths need to go 1,2,3,etc in cyclic order around the polygon, or for a fixed $n$ can they go in any sequence? Also you must be seeking a probability for a single $n$ or a finite range of $n,$ else what probability distribution can you use for covering say all $n>2$?

Comment: No, the side-lengths need not to be in consecutive order. They can have a random order

Comment: $n$ is fixed, sorry for not mentioning it. Edited

Comment: For $n$ moderately large, and a given choice of cyclic order for the $n$ side lengths, the polygon formed will not (I believe) be rigid. So changing it by squishing or otherwise contorting it (preserving all side lengths) will alter what angles are formed.  So to find the probability you want for such fixed $n$ one would need some kind of "state space" for the possible polygons of that type, and a probability distribution on that state space, before finding your probability. It may get complicated and at least the state space and PDF for it would need specifying.

Comment: Aryan-- I put up what is not actually an answer, to explain what I'm asking in my last comment. Are you still interested in your question? If so I'd appreciate some info about the $n=4$ case, as outlined in my non-answer.